# javascrpt, how could we create an object iterating through two arrays which are the key/value pairs before creating them?

Tags: javascript, arrays, file, object, for-loop

I have one doubt:

I am trying to parse a file which contents are two lines which hold data as:

```
'Head' 'Heart' 'Hand'
"0 255 5" "100 1 5" "0 55 155"
```

The first line is a list of body parts, and the second one is a list with each body's parts' gray level.

**The need is to create an object like:**

```
atlas = {
    firstName = grayLevel1,
    secondName = grayLevel2,
    ...
};
```

**So then we would have:**

```
atlas = {
    Head = 0 255 5,
    Heart = 100 1 5,
    Hand = 0 55 155,
...
};
```

I have just managed to read all file, isolate lines and words.

To do that I have written:

```
readTextFile("columna01-es-latin1.txt");

function readTextFile(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                allText = rawFile.responseText;
                console.log('The complete text is', allText);
                let lineArr = intoArray(allText);
                let firstLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[0]);
                let secondLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[1]);

                console.log('Our  first line is: ', lineArr[0]);
                for (let i = 0; i < firstLineWords.length; i++) {
                    console.log(`Our ${i} word in the first line is : ${firstLineWords[i]}`);
                    console.log(`Our ${i} word in the SECOND line is : ${secondLineWords[i]}`);
                }


            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}

function intoArray(lines) {
    // splitting all text data into array "\n" is splitting data from each new line
    //and saving each new line as each element*

    var lineArr = lines.split('\n');

    //just to check if it works output lineArr[index] as below


    return lineArr;


}

function intoWords(line) {


    var wordsArr = line.split('" "');


    return wordsArr;
}
```

To be able to create the object I would do something like:

```
let atlas = {
                        for(let i = 0; i < firstLineWords.length; i++){
                        firstLineWords[i]: secondLineWords[i]
                        }
                    };
```

However it is not a valid syntax.

I would do the previous task into readTextFile()

```
function readTextFile(file) {
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (rawFile.readyState === 4) {
            if (rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0) {
                allText = rawFile.responseText;
                console.log('The complete text is', allText);
                let lineArr = intoArray(allText);
                let firstLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[0]);
                let secondLineWords = intoWords(lineArr[1]);

                console.log('Our  first line is: ', lineArr[0]);
                for (let i = 0; i < firstLineWords.length; i++) {
                    console.log(`Our ${i} word in the first line is : ${firstLineWords[i]}`);
                    console.log(`Our ${i} word in the SECOND line is : ${secondLineWords[i]}`);
                }

                let atlas = {
                    for(let i = 0; i < firstLineWords.length; i++){
                    firstLineWords[i]: secondLineWords[i]
                    }
                };
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
```

*I understand that inside an object we can not iterate through properties that have not been created yet.*

I have also read:

How to iterate in object properties: [Iterate through object properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8312459/iterate-through-object-properties)

Checking objects into arrays:

[How do I check if an array includes an object in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237104/how-do-i-check-if-an-array-includes-an-object-in-javascript)

Loop thought Objects: [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Adding key/value pairs to object dinamically, it is a very close topic, however Ido not see how it could be applied to this example, ✖:

[How can I add a key/value pair to a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168807/how-can-i-add-a-key-value-pair-to-a-javascript-object)

How to iterate into plain Javascript objects:
[How to Loop through plain JavaScript object with objects as members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/921789/how-to-loop-through-plain-javascript-object-with-objects-as-members)

javascript key value pairs: [javascript object key value pairs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36701354/javascript-object-key-value-pairs)

***How could we handle this key/value creation, inside an object?***

Comment: Use square bracket notation. `let atlas = {}; for (...) { atlas[firstLineWords[i]] = secondLineWords[I]; }`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to create an object from an Array of key-value pairs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20059995/how-to-create-an-object-from-an-array-of-key-value-pairs)

Comment: [This looks almost exactly the same as a question you asked earlier today.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49451251/javascript-data-structure-to-group-parts-and-graylevel-xml-or-json)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this solves your problem:

```
var atlas = {};
for(var i = 0 ; i < bodyParts.length ; i++{
    atlas[bodyParts[i]] = grayLevel[i]
}
```

Javascript checks if the key exists in atlas and if it doesn't,it creates it and assigns the respective value of greyLevel.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for? You can reduce the arrays into a single object with key/value pairs equal to the body part and its respective gray levels, like so:

```js
var bodyParts = ['Head', 'Heart', 'Hand'];
var grayLevels = ["0 255 5", "100 1 5", "0 55 155"];

var atlas = bodyParts.reduce(function (res, curr, index) {
  res[curr] = grayLevels[index];
  return res;
}, {});

console.log(atlas);
```

Answer (score 0):

Split the lines, and use `Array.map()` to get two arrays of the texts you want. Then combine them to an object using `Array.reduce()`:

```js
const text = `'Head' 'Heart' 'Hand'
"0 255 5" "100 1 5" "0 55 155"`;

const txtToObj = (txt) => {
  const [l1, l2] = text.split('\n')
    .map((l) => l.match(/\b[^'"]+/g));
    
  return l1.reduce((r, w, i) => {
    r[w] = l2[i];
    
    return r;
  }, {});
};

console.log(txtToObj(text));
```